# Google Guava RangeMap Iteration Order

Tags: java, guava

We have been using the `com.google.common.collect.RangeMap` class in Google's guava library and have found it very useful. In particular, I would like to use the `asMapOfRanges()` method and depend on the iteration order of the returned `Map` to be in the order of the `Range`s in each entry. The implementation of `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableRangeMap` seems to explicitly adhere to this implementation, but it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the JavaDoc anywhere. I'm wondering if I can depend on this behavior on any `RangeMap`, and it was just missed in the JavaDoc, or if iteration order is intended to be unspecified, in which case I should order the results before I iterate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've looked at the implementation also I came to the same conclusion, I mean this code:

```
static final Ordering<Range<?>> RANGE_LEX_ORDERING = new Ordering<Range<?>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Range<?> left, Range<?> right) {
      return ComparisonChain.start()
          .compare(left.lowerBound, right.lowerBound)
          .compare(left.upperBound, right.upperBound)
          .result();
    }
  };
```

Is sorting based on Range...

I also think that @Beta is the indication why this is not documented. They might changed it in future releases. In case I wanted to use it I would have one more additional unit test that would fail in case this changes, it will act as a safety net.

Comment: Making a unit test that will fail if they come back in the wrong order is a great suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry! :) I tried!

Comment: @AndrewRustleund :) np